# Change TagVisualization at runtime - Surface doesn't refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I am working on a WPF-Surface project and have already created  two different TagVisualizations for one ByteTag. Now I want to switch externally (in a normal WPF-Window) between those visualizations (at runtime).

My temporary solution:
For a start I have just written a method, that adds or changes the current visualization (points to different xaml-files) after clicking the external window.

```
private void addTagVisualization(String tagvisualization)
{
     ByteTagVisualizationDefinition def1 = new ByteTagVisualizationDefinition
     {
          Value = 192,
          Source = new Uri(tagvisualization, UriKind.Relative),
          UsesTagOrientation = true,
          TagRemovedBehavior = TagRemovedBehavior.Fade,
          PhysicalCenterOffsetFromTag = new Vector(0, 0)
     };

     TagVisualizer tagvis1 = new TagVisualizer();

     tagvis1.Definitions.Add(def1);

     grid.Children.Add(tagvis1);
}
```

The problem:

When I Click "Change Tagvisualization" in my WPF Window, the Surface gets the new connection but doesn't refresh - so I have to put the Tag up and down to see the new visualization. How can I make the surface recognize an object new - even when it's already on the surface and doesn't move?

I tried everything: invalidateVisual, children.clear(), load the Files via XAMLReader - it's always the same:
I have to put the tag up and down to see the new visualization. I think it's the same problem, like in all the Examples: the tags work, when they are moved around after an example has started. But when I put the tag on the surface before choosing the example - the Application doesn't get the tag....

Does anyone know what to do? I know that this works in the Core-Layer somehow, but there has to be a solution in WPF, too??

Thanks in advance!

---

Second attempt:

I tried to save the contact, to capture it later. It worked a bit better: after I click changeTagVisualization, the tag doesn't lose its "recognition" but only its visualization.
After the click it looks like the tag has no visualization but is recognized by the surface. When I put it up and down, the new TagVisualization appears. What's the missing link??

The XAML-code for the main Window:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow (Namespacedefinitions...)>

   <Grid x:Name="grid" s:Contacts.GotContactCapture="gotIt" />

</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

The C#-Code for the main Window:

```
// Here some global parameters

TagVisualizer tagvis1;
Contact tagContact;
int style = 1;

...

// A method that saves the tag, when added the first time to surface

private void gotIt(object sender, ContactEventArgs e){

tagContact = e.Contact

}

...

// The method which switches between the XAML-Files and loads different visualizations

private void addTagVisualization() {
    ByteTagVisualizationDefinition defByte = ByteTagVisualizationDefinition();
    defByte.value = 9;
    defByte.LostTagTimeout = 0;

    if(style == 1) {
        defByte.Source = new Uri("TagVisualization1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    }
    else {
        defByte.Source = new Uri("TagVisualization2.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    }

    this.tagvis1 = new TagVisualizer();
    tagvis1.Definitions.Add(defByte);
    grid.Children.Add(tagvis1);

}


// I think here is the mistake: a method, which is called from my external window.
// after a click on changeVisualization the style parameter switches
// I clear the old visualization in order to add it once again with a different xaml
// then I capture the object and invalidate

public void setStyle(int style) {
    this.style = style;
    grid.Children.Clear();
    addTagVisualization();
    tag.Capture(tagvis1);
    base.InvalidateVisual();
}
```

Comment: where is your setStyle method called from?

Comment: From a normal WPF Window in the same project. It runs on a seperate Monitor which is connected via VGA to the surface. The WPF-Window has two style-buttons. When I click "style one" for example, the handler access the public method "setStyle" in my SurfaceWindow Class...So the the INPUT for setStyle is "1" or "0" and works quite well, but I think the method
doesn't work quite well. Something is missing...

Comment: what about it "doesn't work quite well"?

Comment: Before I tried to capture the contact, the visualization just was gone after changing the style. Right now, the tag loses the tagvisualization, but the surface still "glows" arround the tag 
- so it seems like it the tag is still captured as a contact but isn't able to refresh the new visualization. So I still have to put the tag up and down to see the new visualization. I could imagine, that the contact object I save, doesn't contain enough information to assign the new xaml-file to the tag...

Comment: if there is a glow around the tag that means it is *not* captured to the tag visualizer

Comment: Hmm... I really don't know what to do. Perhaps you have an idea, when I phrase the question different:

Is it possible to code a programm, that can do following:

First I put a few tags on my surface. Second I start my Programm (the tags normally won't be recognized). Third I click a button "scan tags". And last: the surface recognizes the tags and adds the tagvisualizations...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you added a button to your window and placed that button underneath the mouse even though the mouse button was already pressed.  The button wouldn't automatically 'click' if the mouse button was already pressed when the button appeared beneath it.

TagVisualizer is the same way - it only pays attention to tags that go down on it or that it's formally given control of.  So how do you formally give an element formal control of a contact?  That's where 'capture' comes in.  Find the Contact object that represents the tag and then call `contact.Capture(tagvisualizer)`.  That should do the trick!

Keep in mind though that probably a better design than dynamically creating new TagVisualizers would be to simply modify the Source property of your visualizationdefinition.  Another alternaitve would be to dynamically change the contents of the tagvisualization element itself.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer - your approach worked better: the surface doesn't loose the contact. Unfortunately it doesn't refresh neither. I've added my second attempt to the question, perhaps you can discover the failure? Kind Regards